# eZ publish to resize image not scale

Tags: php, ezpublish

In eZ publish at the moment Im using the following in image.ini.append.php

```
[largepic]
Reference=
Filters[]
Filters[]=geometry/scale=580;270
```

Which does work fine.

However for testing purposes I want to resize the image, scaling it up if needed - the image will be 580x270, even if the original image was lower dimension.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was `scaleexact`

Answer (score 1):

If you put ! after the number it will force to exact size. For example:

```
[largepic]
Reference=
Filters[]
Filters[]=geometry/scale=580!;270!
```